# Error: Invalid signature - provided signature does not match. [woocommerce_rest_authentication_error] on get more the 10 items

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I get the error Error: Invalid signature - provided signature does not match [woocommerce_rest_authentication_error] when useinclude parameter, also I use `per_page = 20`
works fine when use 10 or lower items.
following code work fine.

```
$orders = $woocommerce->get('orders/', array(
            'per_page' => 20,
            'include' => array(554, 553, 550, 549, 548, 547, 546, 545, 544, 543)
));
```

If I extend one or more ids then I get the above mention error

```
$orders = $woocommerce->get('orders/', array(
            'per_page' => 20,
            'include' => array(554, 553, 550, 549, 548, 547, 546, 545, 544, 543, 542, 541)
));
```

I double check all order ids one by one all are correct, and also I debug by using individual id
I get all orders using the following code

```
$orders = $woocommerce->get('orders/', array(
            'per_page' => 20
));
```

Answer (score 1):

I spent almost whole day with this issue. There is a little bug in WooCommerce PHP API Library.

To understand this bug you have to take a look at .../src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/OAuth.php:193

```
\uksort($parameters, 'strcmp');
```

It sorts parameters (by key), but leaves out nested arrays, although `$this->getParameters()` uses `$this->getSortedParameters()`, which is more advanced and sorts also nested arrays.

**So here's the problem:** if `$parameters` has nested array with more than 9 elements, `$parameters` differs from `$this->getParameters()` and more importantly from signed string `$stringToSign`, so OAuth throws an error: **"Invalid signature - provided signature does not match. [woocommerce_rest_authentication_error]"**.

#### Example:

**$parameters**

```
[
  'include' => [
    0 => 554,
    1 => 553,
    2 => 550,
    3 => 549,
    4 => 548,
    5 => 547,
    6 => 546,
    7 => 545,
    8 => 544,
    9 => 543,
    10 => 542,
    11 => 541,
  ],
  ...
];
```

**$this-getParameters();**

```
[
  'include' => [
    0 => 554,
    1 => 553,
    10 => 542, // !!!
    11 => 541, // !!!
    2 => 550,
    3 => 549,
    4 => 548,
    5 => 547,
    6 => 546,
    7 => 545,
    8 => 544,
    9 => 543,
  ],
  ...
];
```

It takes just one small change to solve this issue.

.../src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/OAuth.php:193

```
\uksort($parameters, 'strcmp');
```

change to:

```
$parameters = $this->getSortedParameters($parameters);
```

I also made a pull request: https://github.com/woocommerce/wc-api-php/pull/278